# Matching a city and postcode to a list in G Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Apologies in advance if this question is worded poorly. I'm struggling to find the words to define the issue that I am having / would like to resolve.

I would like to know if there is a way that I can match a city and postcode prefix to a list of postcodes that I have so that the result will tell me if the postcode appears on my postcode list for that city?

I have used the following formula *`=SUMPRODUCT(--(F4='Catchment Area Postcodes'!$A:$BZ))>0`*, to match an individual postcode to a range of postcodes for an individual city, but this is not dynamic if I wish to look up another city.

I would like to know if there is a way to make this dynamic so that it links to the city that I am searching for?

I'm a newbie here, so I can't upload screenshots yet, unfortunately, but Cell F4 features a postcode Prefix (HU4). To make my formula dynamic, I know that I will need to factor in the city, which I select from a drop-down in cell B7.

The range *`Catchment Area Postcodes'!$A:$BZ`* is the full list of cities and postcode prefixes for each. The city names are in column A and the lists of postcodes are in the remaining columns.

Is it possible to add something to my current formula, or is this a dead-end?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: It’s a work spreadsheet and I am not allowed to share it with people outside of my company. It contains customer data, so I’m afraid that I can’t share it. Sorry.

Comment: Eng17, you should be able to create a NEW sheet under your own personal account, manually enter (or copy in) enough data to show what you're trying to do, and share a link to that personal sheet. Saying, "I can't share it" and expecting help is like calling mechanic who's never seen your car and saying, "My car is making funny noises. I can't  bring the car in for you to see it or tell you what make or model it is, but what's wrong with it and how can I fix it?"

Comment: Yeah sure, I recognise that. Unfortunately there isn't any way that I can copy enough of the data that would adequately replicate the issue, without compromising customer privacy. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Sure, I will do. I’ve only just seen the response now.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; D2:E; 2; 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately this didn't work for my purposes.
The result that I would be looking for would be to show whether the postcode I am referencing matches the city, in the list. So a result of 'True' or 'False' for example.

Thank you for offering help though.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to lookup a value in a 2 dimensional array with row headings but no column headings.

The following formula has worked for me:

```
=INDEX('Catchment Area Postcodes'!$B:$BY,SUMPRODUCT(('Catchment Area Postcodes'!$B:$BY=F4)*ROW('Catchment Area Postcodes'!$BY:$BY)),1)
```